# Dynamic Naming of DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have an Address view for users to enter their addresses for both billing and shipping.  So on the Address model I have:

```
public string AddressType { get; set; }
```

Then on the Create Account view I have:

```
<div class="pure-control-group">
    @Html.Action("Init", "Address", new {AddressType="Billing"})
</div>


<div class="pure-control-group">
    @Html.Action("Init", "Address", new {AddressType="Shipping"})
</div>
```

In the Address View I have a number of `input` controls that all render as expected but I also have a Country Dropdown List that I want to dynamically name (the only control I am using the html helper for):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountryId, new SelectList(Model.ValidCountries, "CountryId", "CountryName", Model.SelectedCountryId), null, new {name=Model.AddressType + "_SelectedCountryId", id=Model.AddressType + "_SelectedCountryId"})
```

However when this renders I end up with:

```
<select id="Billing_SelectedCountryId" name="SelectedCountryId">
```

I want:

```
<select id="Billing_SelectedCountryId" name="Billing_SelectedCountryId">
```

I have read that using an upper case N for Name fixes this but as others have said it just adds another property:

```
<select id="Billing_SelectedCountryId" name="SelectedCountryId" Name="Billing_SelectedCountryId">
```

Everything I have read is a bit confusing and I can't make out if anyone found a fix, Is there anyway round this?

Comment: Why would you give your select a `name` attribute that has no relationship to your model and therefore will not bind on postback?

Comment: @StephenMuecke On the `UserAccount` model there is a `Billing_SelectedCountryId` and `Shipping_SelectedCountryId`.  The idea is that the Address view can be used in multiple places throughout the site by passing a prefix depending on which address is being added/updated.

Comment: You have said you model contains 2 address objects (say) `Address BillingAddress` and `Address ShippingAddress` (there should be no need at all for an `string  AddressType` property. Then you create an `EditorTemplate` for type of `Address` and in the main view - `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BillingAddress)` and `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ShippingAddress)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is my first MVC project and was unaware of `EditorTemplate`'s  It looks like this is exactly what I need!  Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you name it correctly - `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml` (assuming your class is named `Address` and the `@model yourAssembly.Address` and use the strongly typed helpers for **ALL** controls

Comment: If you want a `select` with a different name, but the same data populating it, then you could also look at [Html.DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx)   That will allow you to create a `select` with a specific name that you can give it.